# If statement if no value returned

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So, I have this:

```
$user = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE LL_IP='" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "'");
$user->execute();
while($userDATA = $user->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  if( userDATA['LL_IP'] == $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) {
    echo "Logged in";
  }
  else {
    echo "Register / Login";
  }
}
```

I'm trying to get it where if no `$userDATA['LL_IP']` is found. Then it does the `else` statement, but for some reason it's not working.

I've also tried:

```
elseif($userDATA['LL_IP'] == false) {
        echo "Register / Login";
 }
```

But that doesn't work either.

Comment: Try a `print_r` on `$userDATA`, which tell you if you're actually getting a match.

Comment: If your LL_IP is uniq then remove `while`.

Comment: You would be better off to use sessions for your logged-in check / system, the remote address is not very reliable. And you need to do a database query on every request...

Comment: @TiesonT. The `if` part works.  But the `else` doesn't

Comment: @user3186208 You will NEVER reach that else condition.

Comment: @user3186208 Of course the `if` part works, if a row is found, that condition is always true because you already set that condition in the query.

Comment: @jeroen, but the problem was, if the data wasn't found in the database. Which is where is where I had the problem.  But I got is answered, so it's all good.

Comment: @user3186208 If no row is found, the whole `while` loop is skipped because you are doing a `while (false)` so nothing in there is executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to check if a row was found, you can replace the loop with an `if` statement:

```
if($userDATA = $user->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    echo "Logged in";
}
else
{
    echo "Register / Login";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is faulty.  You already query only for cases where `LL_IP` equals `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`.  Why would expect to EVER gat a result turned where your if conditional wouldn't match.

It seems to me that all you would need to do in this case is to check to see if the number of records returned in the result set is greater than 1.

By the way, you should at least escape `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` before using it in a query, or better yet, since you are already using a prepared statement, you could use a parametrized value.

Your logic should be something like this:

```
// specify maybe a primary key field in query. No need for SELECT *    
$query = "SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM `users` WHERE LL_IP = :ip_address LIMIT 1"; 
$user->prepare($query);
$user->bindParam(':ip_address', $_SERvER['REMOTE_ADDR'], PDO::PARAM_STR]);
$user->execute();
if('1' === $user->fetchColumn(0)) {
   // logged in
} else {
   // not logged in
}
```

I also agree with comment from @jeroen above that you really shouldn't rely on an IP address to determine any sort of login status.  IP addresses can change unpredictably (particularly for mobile users).

Comment: `rowCount` will not accurately reflect the number of rows affected by a SELECT statement. See Example #2 of the manual entry for it

Comment: @CrayonViolent `rowCount()` is not reliable across all database supported by PDO, but is supported for MySQL which is tagged on the OP. If you truly needed a database agnostic implementation then you should use `SELECT COUNT(*)`.

Comment: Are you sure about that? The user submitted comments for `rowCount` seem to suggest otherwise

Comment: @CrayonViolent I pretty sure, though, it could be because I typically use mysqlnd. I should probably update the answer to make it more generic though.

Answer (score 0):

```
$user = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE LL_IP='" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "'");
$user->execute();
if ($user->fetchColumn() > 0) {
  // logged in
} else {
  // not logged in
}
```

[The manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) (see example #2) says to use [`fetchColumn`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php)